# Mozilla Firefox > Developer Tools > Console > XHR Response Panels (height)

Tags: firefox, console, mozilla, devtools

Earlier version of Firefox used the full real estate for these panels, but now they seem fixed at 5 lines, which ... is not very easy to use anymore.

[image: Indicated by the red arrows]
Is there a configuration or setting somewhere that can revert this change to the full available height? Or to make them resizable at least? Thank you.

EDIT: [found this](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1196937)